# How to remove empty cells in UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

i am trying to display a simple `UITableView` with some data. I wish to set the static height of the `UITableView` so that it doesn't displays empty cells at the end of the table. how do I do that?

code:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section { 
    NSLog(@"%d", [arr count]);
    return [arr count];
}
```

Comment: set numberOfRows properly then it wont show empty cells

Answer (score 923, accepted):

Set a zero height table footer view (perhaps in your `viewDidLoad` method), like so:

**Swift:**

```
tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
```

**Objective-C:**

```
tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
```

Because the table thinks there is a footer to show, it doesn't display any cells beyond those you explicitly asked for.

**Interface builder pro-tip:**

If you are using a **xib/Storyboard**, you can just drag a UIView (with height 0pt) onto the bottom of the UITableView.

Comment: In what method would that line of code be added? tableView willDisplayFooterView??

Comment: @Jupiter869 I just put it in the ViewDidLoad and it works

Comment: Thanks, I tried with below code. But after selecting cells, lines will disappear. So, Don't use this  : ` if(indexPath.row != self.menuItems.count){
        UIImageView *line = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, 320, 1)];
        line.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        [cell addSubview:line];
    }`

Comment: With the news syntax you can do: tableView.tableFooterView = [UIView new];

Comment: SWIFT 2.0 : `self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRectZero)`

Comment: Adding the 0 height view to the table view below any cells in the storyboard worked perfectly.

Comment: **SWIFT 3.0** works great with `tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()`

Answer (score 104):

**Swift 3 syntax:**

```
tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: .zero)
```

**Swift syntax: < 2.0**

```
tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zeroRect)
```

**Swift 2.0 syntax:**

```
tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)
```

Comment: It's now tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)

Comment: Tested with ios 8+ and works fine.

Comment: Just in case anybody’s interested, Swift actually lets you be even more concise: `tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: .zero)`

Comment: Shorter! `tableView.tablFooterView = UIView()`

Answer (score 67):

In the Storyboard, select the `UITableView`, and modify the property Style from `Plain` to `Grouped`.

Comment: best and most straight forward answer 1

Comment: But it adds extra spacing above and below table sections.

Comment: also doable in code.

Answer (score 17):

Implemented with swift on Xcode 6.1

```
self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRectZero)
self.tableView.tableFooterView?.hidden = true
```

The second line of code does not cause any effect on presentation, you can use to check if is hidden or not.

Answer taken from this link
[Fail to hide empty cells in UITableView Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24470656/fail-to-hide-empty-cells-in-uitableview-swift)

Comment: This did it for me using Swift & XCode 6.1! Had tried Swift-equivalent versions of the answers above but with no success.

Answer (score 11):

*I can not add comment as of now so adding this as an answer.*

@Andy's answer is good and the same results can be achieved with the following line of code:

```
tableView.tableFooterView = [UIView new];
```

'new' method belongs to `NSObject` class and invokes `alloc` and `init` methods for `UIView`.

Comment: This works out OK, but isn't technically the same as Andy's answer. Using new simply calls the "init" method, but there's no guarantee that [myView init] and [myView initWithFrame:CGRectZero] are the same, even though in today's implementation, they appear to be.

Answer (score 8):

I tried the code:

```
tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
```

In the **viewDidLoad** section and xcode6 showed a warning. I have put a "self." in front of it and now it works fine. so the working code I use is:

```
self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
```

Answer (score 3):

or you can call tableView method to set the footer height in 1 point, and it will add an last line, but you can hide it too, by setting footer background color.

code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView,heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
     return 1
}
```

[looks like last line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LRQ6.png)

Answer (score 2):

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zeroRect)

/// OR 

    self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Using `UITableViewController`**

The solution accepted will change the height of the `TableViewCell`. To fix that, perform following steps:

1. Write code snippet given below in `ViewDidLoad` method.

   `tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];`
2. Add following method in the `TableViewClass.m` file.

   ```
   - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
   {
       return (cell height set on storyboard); 
   }
   ```

That's it. You can build and run your project.

Answer (score 0):

in the below method:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (([array count]*65) > [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height - 66)
    {
        Table.frame = CGRectMake(0, 66, self.view.frame.size.width, [array count]*65)); 
    }
    else
    {
        Table.frame = CGRectMake(0, 66, self.view.frame.size.width, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height - 66);
    }
    return [array count];
}
```

here 65 is the height of the cell and 66 is the height of the navigation bar in UIViewController.