# Fail to hide empty cells in UITableView Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, swift

I'm using UITableView in a swift application, and using my own custom UITableViewCell.

When trying to hide the empty cells in the UITableView, its still have the white background.

Under the UITableView I have a background image (UImageView).

I'v already try to hide those cells, and actually they are hidden, but I still have a white background, using this code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var tblView =  UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0,y: 0,width: 0,height: 0))
    tblView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    tableView.tableFooterView = tblView

    var nipName=UINib(nibName: "CustomCell", bundle:nil)
    self.tableView.registerNib(nipName, forCellReuseIdentifier: "CustomCell")
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here Is the solution:

```
tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0))
tableView.tableFooterView?.isHidden = true
tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
```

Comment: `UIView does not have a member named 'hidden'` and that line isn't necessary anyway.

Answer (score 31):

A cleaner solution is:

```
tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRectZero)
```

Nothing else is needed.

Comment: @user3210784 I believe perhaps this must be the accepted answer as it does the job with much less code than the accepted answer ?

Comment: absolutely correct answer. A little addition: you need to mention the IBOutlet for tableView to make this work.

Answer (score 3):

SWIFT 3

tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: .zero)

Answer (score 0):

Another simpler solution for this issue is setting the background with an image for your tableView.The image should be plain white if you just need a white background for your non-data cells or you can set your custom image as well for your tableview background.So data with cells would have normal background and for the non-data cell it will show your background image:

```
 self.tableViewName.backgroundColor = UIColor (patternImage: UIImage(named:
 "imageName.jpg")!)
```

Answer (score 0):

Either of these work for me in Swift 3.0

**Method - 1**

```
let footerView =  UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)
tableView.tableFooterView = footerView
tableView.tableFooterView?.isHidden = true
tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear()
```

**Method - 2**

```
 tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3** : Simplest way

```
tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
```