# How to remove empty cells from UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have a UITableView with cells having data from server response which means not everytime all the cells displays the data. So I need to remove those "empty" cells.I have already searched and could not find any possible solution. The solution from [How to remove empty cells in UITableView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14520185/how-to-remove-empty-cells-in-uitableview) didn't work out. Actually it made my tableview disappear.

I need another solution other than the addition of a footer view. Is there any?

Comment: Have you try to add empty footer view so it will hide all unwanted empty cell from tableview?

Comment: Do you any code? If you do then please share it. That would make things clearer and easy to understand.

Comment: can you check this link for remove cells in tableview http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369831/eliminate-extra-separators-below-uitableview

Comment: @CodeChanger I've already tried that. Not working. It made my tableview disappear.

Comment: @PrissyEve same solution as I above said.. Not working..

Comment: @NiravD I've not added any empty objects since it is coming from server response.

Comment: check server value if server value is empty do not add in array. you can make new array for sever non nil objects. For empty cell use footer view.

Comment: do not add the empty values to the `datasource` of `tableView`.

Comment: @Hamed i just update my answer take a look

Answer (score 8):

You should check your data which is coming from the server and only add not nil data to tableview data source.

After that reload your tableview.

This way your tableview won't have any empty cells. simple.

In case your problem is that number of cell being displayed doesn't fill up your view

you can try

```
tableview.tableFooterView = UIView()
```

Comment: I've already checked and if there is non-null data only the tableview gets reloaded. otherwise an alert will show with "no data" message.

Comment: I'm talking about the particular data for each cell, just run the server response through "for" loop and add only not nil data into data source

Comment: @Hamed i just update my answer take a look

Answer (score 4):

You can use one of the two methods.

```
1. self.tableView.tableFooterView.frame = CGRectZero;
2. self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   return [[UIView alloc]init];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about separators; You can remove that by changing property "separator" of UITableView.

[image]

But this will also affect data cells. You must add custom separator line in your data cell.

Comment: op's ques is about to remove empty cell not for cell separator, have you seen?

Comment: Actually, my issue was to remove empty cells, I've found the solution. Just give table view height constraint in the storyboard and drag the same into your .h file. Now add the following code just before/after you reload the table: **tableviewHeight=[array count]*[row height];**. But this resulted in a cell separator for the final cell which I don't need. So I combined your solution with mine and its working perfectly now!

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are adding data in `cell` by `array`. So only add data in array when you receive the data from server. If you do not receive data from server don't add anything. And return `numberOfRows` your `array`s count.

Answer (score 0):

To remove empty cells at bottom of the tableview

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0.01
}
```

or use this

```
self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it from nib also.

From source:

```
    - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return 0.01f;
    }

     - (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
     {        
       return [UIView new];
    }
```