# why does UITableView render extra rows(more than the rows in the data array)?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

below I have a picture attached of a uitableview I am using `numberOfRowsInSection` to return `data.count` however more rows show up than are in the count, and I only have one section. So why do the extra rows show up? If I have a tableview as the only subview of the main content view I do not have this problem, but I have another view on the same level in the view hierarchy as the uitableview.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove empty cells in UITableView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14520185/how-to-remove-empty-cells-in-uitableview)

Answer (score 7):

`UIKit` does not create the empty rows when the `tableView` has a `footerView` displayed below the table cells. You can add one with zero height. So, Its not visible to the user. In the `viewDidLoad` method of your `tableView` .Create a new `UIView` with a `zero rect frame` and use it to set the `tableFooterView` property of the `tableView`:

```
yourTableViewName.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, they are separation lines, this happens when you set the table height greater than the content height, one thing you can do is set your separator to "None" or you can set the tableView height close to the height of your content.

Greetings, hope this help someone.